# How to check a file before delete in android

Tags: android, file

I know how to delete a file, it's:

```
File file = new File(path);
file.delete();
```

Can I **test that the file is currenlty in use without rooting my device**?
For exmple I want to check if the file is open before i can delete it.

I want to be able to catch errors with a try catch sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `try/catch` clause.

```
try {
    Files.delete(path);
} catch (NoSuchFileException x) {
    System.err.format("%s: no such" + " file or directory%n", path);
} catch (DirectoryNotEmptyException x) {
    System.err.format("%s not empty%n", path);
} catch (IOException x) {
    // File permission problems are caught here.
    System.err.println(x);
}
```

You can find more information [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/delete.html).